# SOQL Limit hit inside FOR Loop

Tags: governorlimits

I apologise in advance as i know this should be simple and other people ask this same question but no matter how i try to re-write my code i keep getting errors so ive given in and thought id ask for some help.

For each price book entry against the standard price book, i need to find matching non-standard price book entrys that have the same Product2Id and update them. 
My code is below and obviously im hitting the SOQL query limit since its inside the for loop.

```
    pricebook2 SPB = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsActive = true AND IsStandard = true];   
    String SPBId = SPB.Id;  

 //get book entries for the standard price book
    List<pricebookEntry> StandardPBEntries = [SELECT Id,Product2Id FROM pricebookEntry WHERE priceBook2Id = :SPBId];  

 //loop around standard price book entries looking for matches against non standard entries
    for (pricebookEntry StandardEntry : StandardPBEntries) 
           {              
            String prod2Id  = StandardEntry.Product2Id;

             //look for matches
             List<pricebookEntry> Matches = [SELECT Id, Name, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, IsActive, Is_Negotiated__c FROM PricebookEntry 
                                            where product2id = :prod2Id and isactive = true 
                                            and priceBook2Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsActive = true AND IsStandard = false)];

                 if(Matches.size() > 0)                    
                 {
                    for (pricebookEntry aMatch : Matches)
                    {
                        //update required data
                    }                           
                 }       

            }
```

Comment: Here you can move the SOQL outside the loop and store `prod2Id` value in a `Set<Id>` and use this set in the `SOQL` query with `IN: idsSet`.

Answer (score 5):

Do it like this:

```
pricebook2 SPB = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsActive = true AND IsStandard = true];   
String SPBId = SPB.Id;  

//get book entries for the standard price book
List<pricebookEntry> StandardPBEntries = [SELECT Id,Product2Id FROM pricebookEntry WHERE priceBook2Id = :SPBId];  

 //loop around standard price book entries looking for matches against non standard entries
Set<Id> product2IdsSet = new Set<Id>();
for(pricebookEntry StandardEntry : StandardPBEntries){            
    product2IdsSet.add(StandardEntry.Product2Id);                
}


//look for matches
List<pricebookEntry> Matches = [SELECT Id, Name, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, IsActive, Is_Negotiated__c FROM PricebookEntry 
                                where product2id IN: product2IdsSet and isactive = true 
                                AND priceBook2Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsActive = true AND IsStandard = false)];

for(pricebookEntry aMatch : Matches){
    //update required data
}
```

There is no need to add the `size()` check, foreach will handle this even if there is no record returned by the query.

Comment: Just realised another issue i have with this. During the loop, i need to set the values against the non-standard entry to match is corresponding standard entry. In order to do this is a Set<> no longer appropriate? Could i use a map for this?

Comment: Sure, we can modify the collection as per the need.

Comment: So how would i modify the collection and the loop so for each aMatch i can set all the fields against that priceBookEntry to the values from the same fields against the standard price book entry with that matching product2Id?

Comment: If you want to update some other fields of `pricebookEntry` then you can do the same in the loop. and finally, do `update Matckes;`;

Comment: i understand how to do the update but im having a little trouble setting up the Map<> so i have access to the standard price book entry values without doing a SOQL inside the loop to retrieve it. So at the moment i have the product2Ids in a List, but i need access to the other values on the standard entry too so i can use them to update the match inside the loop.